# MySQL/MariaDB lock over previous lock

Tags: mysql, multithreading, locking, mariadb

I have the following full lock on tables:

```
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 WRITE;
```

I would like to add one more table to the lock some time later (in the same session). So I execute

```
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 WRITE, t3 WRITE;
```

This seems to work just fine. My question is: is this safe? I mean, what internally happens in the database? Does it unlock the t1,t2 tables first and then lock t1,t2,t3 at once, making a possibility of unwanted access to any of the tables before the three are actually locked?

I am using MariaDB and I was reading the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/lock-tables-and-unlock-tables/), but didn't find the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOCK TABLES` is for MyISAM tables.  If you are using InnoDB, switch to `BEGIN...COMMIT` and learn about "transactions" and don't use `LOCK`.

When using `LOCK TABLES`, you get *one* chance to lock *all* the tables you need.  In your example, the locks will be released on the 2 tables before acquiring the locks on the 3 tables.  During that time, some other connection could grab t1 and/or t2.  This is likely to mess up your design.

Since MariaDB is based on MySQL, [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html) provides the explicit answer:

> If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while
>   already holding locks, its existing locks are released implicitly
>   before the new locks are granted.

(If you are using the Aria engine, I don't know what the answer is.)